# Making an object bounce of an other object that is moved by mouseY/mouseX in processing

Tags: processing

I am pretty new with processing and need some help. I'm trying to build a simple kickball game. Easy idea: when the ball hits the yellow bar, the ball bounces of. To keep the ball "alive" you have to make it bounce of the yellow bar. I've successfully found code for the bouncing ball (it now bounces of the bottom of the window), and I've also successfully created a bar that moves with the mouse. What I haven't been able to create so far is for the ball to actually bounce of the bar. Looking for som help here!! Thanks!!

```java
float ballX = 100;
float ballY = 0;
float h = 50;
int x, y;


//create a variable for speed
float speedY = 2;

void setup() {
  size(400,400);
  smooth();
  noStroke();

  // change the mode we draw circles so they are
  // aligned in the top left
  ellipseMode(CORNER);

}

void draw() {
  //clear the background and set the fill colour
  background(0);
  fill(255);



  //draw the circle in it's current position
  ellipse(ballX, ballY, h,h);

  //add a little gravity to the speed
  speedY = speedY + 0.5;  

  //add speed to the ball's
  ballY = ballY + speedY; 


  //bar
   x = mouseX;
  y = mouseY;
  fill(255, 255, 0);
 rect(x, y, 50, 10);

  if (ballY > height - h) {
    // set the position to be on the floor
    ballY = height - h;
    // and make the y speed 90% of what it was,
    // but in the opposite direction
    speedY = speedY * -0.9;

    //switch the direction
    //speedY = speedY;
  }
  else if (ballY <= 0) { 
    // if the ball hits the top,
    // make it bounce off
    speedY = -speedY;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd warn you against just copy-pasting code you found on the internet. You have to really understand what it's doing, otherwise you're going to have a ton of headaches as your code becomes more complicated. Try to rewrite the logic yourself, that way you understand exactly how the bouncing works.

To figure out whether the ball is intersecting the paddle, I'd recommend taking out a piece of paper and a pencil and drawing some examples. Try to figure out a pattern of what the position and size of the ball and paddle are when they're intersecting.

But basically, you need to check whether the ball is "inside" the bounds of the rectangle. This is true if the ball is to the right of the left side of the paddle, to the left of the right side of the paddle, below the top of the paddle, and above the bottom of the paddle.